# LibreOffice 7.5.9.2 LibreOffice/Help file not found

Tags: 22.04, firefox, libreoffice

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS; Firefox 120.0.1 snap; LibreOffice 7.5.9.2 (and helppack)

Invoking Help/LibreOffice Help  (or F1) results in:

```
Firefox can’t find the file at /tmp/lu156338ojxf.tmp/NewHelp0.html
Chromium 120.0.xx snap doesn't work either (ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
```

/tmp/luxxxx.tmp and /tmp/luxxxx.tmp/NewHelp#.html are generated; 644 and 600, respectively and owner and group are my login name.

The NewHelp file points to url='file:///opt/libreoffice7.5/program/../help/en-US/noscript.html' and url='file:///opt/libreoffice7.5/program/../help/index.html?Target=xxx
which are all there.

This pointing to /tmp/lu* is new with 7.5 and appears to be a problem for browsers, but I've been unable to find a solution.
Problem started with 7.5 installs, previous 7.3 installs ok.

All other aspects of LibreOffice seem to work fine.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, in the end, I had to uninstall and remove all hidden files.

Then manually install it using Terminal.

It is worth checking your language settings for Ubuntu and after install of Libre office as if they different can cause issue!.

Hope this helps